# Who was the first avatar?

Tags: avatar

I have seen the complete series of The Last Airbender and also waiting for the 2nd Book of Avatar: Legend of Korra. But yet i haven't heard of who was and which element was the First Avatar. Is there any information about him/her?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Avatar Wan](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Wan) was the first Avatar, and he lived about 10 thousand years before Korra. He was succeeded by a firebender, implying that he was an earthbender originally, but as far as I know, it hasn't been specifically said if the cycle followed perfectly from the first Avatar to the second.

[image: Wan]

Comment: He was not an earthbender, he was a firebender first.  It was the first element he was given by the lion turtles and he mastered it by training with the dragon in the wilds.  He then went around to different lion turtles and gained the other elements with raava and this is the order of the avatar reincarnation cycle.  Fire > Air > Water > Earth.

Comment: How do you know he was succeeded by a firebender?